# Service pack 3 or any other solution?

Tags: windows-xp

I have service pack 3 on my computer and operating system is Windows XP. My computer model is HP Pavilion f1503.Windows XP is going to be unsupported from April 2014. What should I do? Should I upgrade to some other operating system, or do anything else?

Comment: Its rumored that come April 2014 the day support has ended within a very short amount of time ( 24 hours ) the evil people that exists in this world have a whole set of exploits that attack Windows XP.  We can't tell you what you should use instead of Windows XP but what you should not use is Windows XP because of the security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly recommended that you upgrade to a newer system - there a both security issues and compatibility issues with Win XP and they'll only increase.

What you should consider is costs (new operating system, maybe new computer if it can't support the new OS) and compatibility if you use some legacy programs.
So what do you use the computer for? browsing the internet, typing documents, watching online movies or more than that?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't afford a new system, then find yourself a new Linux distribution that you like, backup your data, replace Windows XP with the Linux ditsro of your choice, and copy your data back. If all you do is surf the Internet on this system, and check email, Facebook, IM, watch videos, etc., then the Linux distro will breathe new life into your system.  If you need it for any specialty software, then consider/research whether that application will run in WINE on Linux. WINE allows you to run Windows applications within an emulator.

The point of my post is that just because the OS is no longer supported doesn't mean that the hardware is no longer good as well.  The hardware may be perfect for what you have to do.  Expand your options... you may be surprised what you find.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends of the use you make of this computer. By the way, HP Pavilion f1503 is the reference of a monitor, not a computer. Here are some suggestions:

1. If you use this computer for web browsing, text editing and other "simple" applications, I recommend installing a light version of linux. There are lots of pages that will guide you through the choice and installation to the distribution that will suite your needs.
2. If you run some specialized (professional) legacy applications on this computer, leave it as is but disconnect it from the internet, without ever connecting it again!
3. If this computer is rather recent and Windows is mandatory for you, consider buying and installing Windows 7, for example.

We need more details about the configuration and the **usage you make** of your computer to be more specific in our advices.